# Android - Retrieve data as multiline (i.e. with linebreaks) from internal storage datafile

Tags: java, android, android-activity, multiline, line-breaks

I am a total newbie when it comes to both java and android coding. However, I am trying to piece together a simple notepad widget and app. It's basically a widget which displays the note text in a textView and an activity which can be loaded by tapping the widget. In the activity I have an EditText and two buttons - one to save the note text and one to cancel and close the activity.

An example of note-text entered in the EditText could be:

Buy milk
Kiss girlfriend
Bother Snape

When I save my note data from the activity, it saves my note data to an internal storage file. It then updates the widget and here my note-text is shown WITH linebreaks. But if I then open my activity to edit the text it loads the note-text as a single line file and not a multiline file.

Do any of you guys have suggestions for what I could do to load my note-data as multiline text with linebreaks?

Here's my activity code:

```
package dk.mfoller.android.basicnote;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import java.io.*;

public class BasicNoteActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Button saveBtn;
private Button cancelBtn;
private EditText inputTxt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Defines objects
    saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.basicNoteActivity_save); 
    cancelBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.basicNoteActivity_cancel);
    inputTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.basicNoteActivity_input);

    // Calls a function to update/replace the displayed note text
    readNoteData();

    // Creates event handler for the save-button
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Calls a function to write to a file
            writeToFile();

            // Updates the displayed text in the widget
            String noteinput = inputTxt.getText().toString();
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews("dk.mfoller.android.basicnote", R.drawable.main_widget);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.basicNoteWidget_notetext, noteinput);
            // Updates the actual widget - NOTE: This updates ALL instances of the widget
            ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(getBaseContext(), BasicNoteWidget.class);
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getBaseContext()).updateAppWidget(cn, views);


        }
    });

    // Creates event handler for the cancel-button
    cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}

// A function to write to a file
protected void writeToFile() {
    String FILENAME = "basicNote_data";
    String noteinput = inputTxt.getText().toString();

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        //noteinput.replace("\\r", "\n");
        fos.write(noteinput.getBytes());
        fos.close();

        // Displays a popup
        Toast.makeText(this, "Note saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// A function to read from a file on load
protected void readNoteData() {
    String FILENAME = "basicNote_data";

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        // How do I make this load as multiline text?!?!
        String line = null;
        String output = "";

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            output += line;
        }
        // Updates/replaces the displayed note text
        if(output != "") {
            inputTxt.setText(output);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Thanks in advance! ..oh, and please be very specific. Like I said: I'm a total newbie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readLine()` call does *not* include the end-of-line characters.

Quickest solution is to change the read loop in `readNoteData`:

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    output += line + "\n";
}
```

You could also just read in the entire file and skip that step, but get this working first.

See the [BufferedReader.readLine()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) docs for info.

Comment: You are a God send! I knew it would be something rather simple.. But how do you read the entire file then?